# IF Inside JSON Encode

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, json

I'm using full calendar from Arshaw, this is how I'm adding events to the calendar

```
echo json_encode(array(

        array(
            'id' => 111,
            'title' => "Place Date",
            'start' => "$place_date[0]",
            'color' => "purple"
        ),

        array(
            'id' => 222,
            'title' => "Due Date",
            'start' => "$due_date[0]",
            'color' => "red"
        ),

        array(
            'id' => 333,
            'title' => "Confirmed",
            'start' => "$confirmdate[0]",
            'end' => "$promisedate[0]",
            'color' => "blue"
        )

    ));


}
```

I don't always have information about "confirmdate" so I need to perform an if statement to check if my mysql returns an empty value or not, I like to achieve something like this:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($confirmdate[0] > 0) {
echo  array(
            'id' => 333,
            'title' => "Confirmed",
            'start' => "$confirmdate[0]",
            'end' => "$promisedate[0]",
            'color' => "blue"
        )
}
```

Is there a way to perform an if like this inside a json_encode?

Comment: I don't think you want to call `mysqli_num_rows` like that. I took it out in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to conditionalize an entire element in an `array()` call (the fact that it's in `json_encode` is immaterial). Construct your array in multiple steps:

```
$result = array(
    array(
        'id' => 111,
        'title' => "Place Date",
        'start' => "$place_date[0]",
        'color' => "purple"
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 222,
        'title' => "Due Date",
        'start' => "$due_date[0]",
        'color' => "red"
    )
);

if ($confirmdate[0] > 0) {
    $result[] = array(
        'id' => 333,
        'title' => "Confirmed",
        'start' => "$confirmdate[0]",
        'end' => "$promisedate[0]",
        'color' => "blue"
    );
}

echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: I didn't know you needed to be an expert to know how to add something to an array.